# Cannot serialize Object to ViewState only Session

Tags: serialization, viewstate

I have a class that is marked as serializable and have no problem storing it in the Session but when I attempt to save it in the ViewState I get:

Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Error serializing value

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that view state serialization is done by the [`LosFormatter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.losformatter.aspx) class while session serialization is done by the [`BinaryFormatter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx) class. The two are subtly different and one of these subtle differences is probably causing your problem.

Take a look at [this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/vga/archive/2004/06/09/ViewstateSerializationOneMoreTime.aspx) and the documentation for `LosFormatter` to see if you can find some clues about what is causing your problem.

Comment: "this article" address changed to: http://weblogs.asp.net/vga/archive/2004/06/09/ViewstateSerializationOneMoreTime.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Well it also depends what kind of session do you use. If it's in-proc, then serialization doesn't take place at all. Your objects get stored into memory.